# Detect 5G NR (SA/NSA) in my Android Application

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellinfo, 5g

I am trying to detect 5G network. I use the telephony manager to get [NETWORK_TYPE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getNetworkType()). Even if I am in 5G network coverage and my phone shows 5G, I do not get NETWORK_TYPE_NR. The NETWORK_TYPE is always 13 i.e. LTE.
The Phones Engineering service mode shows NR related data.
Is there any way to detect NR (Standalone or Non-Standalone) mode?

I also need to get the Cell Information for NR data. I use [telephonyManager.getAllCellinfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getAllCellInfo()), but I never get an instance of [cellinfonr](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfoNr).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem for a few weeks ago. In my case, I want to detect 5G network on Galaxy S20-5G but the `getDataNetworkType()` always return 13 `NETWORK_TYPE_LTE`. 
Following by [netmonster-core](https://github.com/mroczis/netmonster-core) strategy, and here is the code that I extract from them to solve my problem.

```
public boolean isNRConnected(TelephonyManager telephonyManager) {
    try {
        Object obj = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName())
                .getDeclaredMethod("getServiceState", new Class[0]).invoke(telephonyManager, new Object[0]);
        // try extracting from string
        String serviceState = obj.toString();
        boolean is5gActive = serviceState.contains("nrState=CONNECTED") ||
                serviceState.contains("nsaState=5") ||
                (serviceState.contains("EnDc=true") &&
                        serviceState.contains("5G Allocated=true"));
        if (is5gActive) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is full detector class from [netmonster-core](https://github.com/mroczis/netmonster-core):
([DetectorLteAdvancedNrServiceState.kt](https://github.com/mroczis/netmonster-core/blob/master/library/src/main/java/cz/mroczis/netmonster/core/feature/detect/DetectorLteAdvancedNrServiceState.kt#L69))

Comment: @Sophoun Thanks for the answer. This detects if I am on 5G or not, but is there anything from which I can get "cellinfonr" object. GetallCellinfo() api does not return nr details even if I am in 5G coverage.

Comment: So after a lot of testing, I figured out that we get the "Cellinfonr" object only on NR-SA devices and not on NR-NSA devices. on NR-NSA devices we can detect 5G using the above answer and can get NR signal info from "CellSignalStrengthNr" api.

Comment: @AkshayChougule can you please share some code as to how you get CellSignalStrengthNr, because TelephonyManager returns CellInfoLTE instance when the device is in NR-NSA.

Comment: @HashimAli Use telephonyManager.getSignalStrength();

Comment: NR state is now masked in Android 12